# How to transfer a collection of pictures from react(axios) to ASP.NET Core server?

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi, minimal-apis

The problem is that I can't write a request to send an array of files to endpoint.

About the server-side: the project server is built on ASP.NET Core (Minimal API).

Endpoint:

```
public static IEndpointRouteBuilder MapImagesEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder)
{
    builder.MapPost("/images", LoadImages)
        .DisableAntiforgery();
    return builder;
}

private static async Task<IResult> LoadImages(
    HttpContext context,
    IImageService imageService,
    [FromForm] List<IFormFile> images) // The IFromFileCollection variant was also used
{
    try
    {
        return Results.Ok(await imageService.LoadImagesAsync(images));
    }
    catch
    {
        return Results.BadRequest(new ErrorDto("An unexpected error occurred while loading the image."));
    }
}
```

The project's client side is built using React. Axios is used to send requests to the server.

Request:

```
const data = new FormData();
images.forEach((image) => {
    data.append("images", image);
});
await Api.UploadImages(data);

static async UploadImages(images: FormData): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return axiosApi.post(
        "/images/images", // This is the correct path, don't mind that it doesn't match what is     written in MapImagesEndpoints().
        images,
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
    });
}
```

I tried changing `List<IFromFile>` to `IFromFileCollection`, but I still don't understand how to write the query correctly.

In all cases I got an error on the server side that the request cannot be read.

Comment: First of all, check the network tab in your browser’s developer tools to see if the request is sent properly with the file data attached to it.
If you found in the network log your file hasn't been sent accordingly, then on the client side, you can use `data.append("files", image);` instead of `data.append("images", image);` to match the name of the parameter on the server side1. 
Alternatively, you can use `[FromForm(Name = "images")] FormCollection` files on the server side to match the name of the data on the client side.

Comment: On the server side, you can use `[FromForm] IFormCollection` files instead of `[FromForm] List<IFormFile>` images to receive the multiple files from the request. 
Then you can access the files by using files.Files property.